# Android Fragment and Dependency Injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dependencies, fragment, code-injection

as the title says, I'm trying to figure out which one is the best way to inject a dependency in a Fragment.
I want to be independent from external frameworks like RoboGuice etc.

Now, in the simplest way possible, I have an interface that abstracts some kind of logic, and, from an Activity, I want to inject an implementation of this interface. I know that I have to provide a default constructor for my fragment, since the system might need to recreate the fragment at some point, and that the usual way to create a new instance of the fragment is to provide static method that handles the creation like this:

```
public static Fragment newInstance() {
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ...
    final Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

How can I pass my dependency to the fragment? Should I make it implement the Parcelable or Serializable interfaces and then pack it in the Bundle? Is there some other way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution is to declare an interface which is declaring the Dependencies required for the Fragment. Then let the Context of the Fragment implement this interface, and poll the dependencies when needed from the Context.

Contract:

```
public interface MyDependencies {

    MyDep getDep();

}
```

Activity:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements MyDependencies {

    @Override
    public MyDep getDep(){
       return createMyDependencyOrGetItFromASingletonOrGetItFromApplication()
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){
     super.onActivityCreated(b)

     if (getActivity() instanceOf MyDependencies) {
         MyDep dep = ((MyDependencies) getActivity).getDep();
     } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("Context does not support the Fragment, implement MyDependencies")
     }
}
```

So, in fact, there is no unnecessary coupling to the Activity because the contract is defined by an interface.

Comment: Got to love that method name "createMyDependencyOrGetItFromASingletonOrGetItFromApplication" lol

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you grab the dependency from your activity?

```
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle b){
     super.onActivityCreated(b)
     DependencyClass c = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getDependency();
}
```

Comment: If I do like this I'll end up coupling the Fragment to the Activity right?
I still want the Fragment to be independent and reusable.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't pass in the dependency via the constructor (if you need a default constructor), and you don't want to use a dependency injection lib like Dagger or RoboGuice, the other classic way is to a setter to "inject" the dependency.

```
Fragment MyFragment {

Depend mDepend;

....


    public void setDepend(Depend depend) {
        mDepend = depend;
    }

}
```

Then in your activity you can inject the dependency in the onCreate method.

so something like this in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    MapFragment wrapperFragment = new WrapperFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.map_container, wrapperFragment).commit();
    // find the fragment
    // call the setter
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when android recreates the fragment it uses the default constructor and doesn't call the set methods, even though they have been called previously.